# How to remove line on TabBar in iOS10

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, ios10, uitabbar

Createa a project with custom `TabBar` , its work perfect in `iOS` up to 9 but in `iOS 10` i have a problem with `TabBar` line on top of the `TabBar`.

[image]

***Tried following code:***

```
UITabBarController *Tabbar;

[[UITabBar appearance] setShadowImage:[[UIImage alloc] init]];
```

its work in `iOS9` not in `iOS10`.
I tried to apply this to the `TabBar`

***1) Try :***

```
   [Tabbar.tabBar setShadowImage:[[UIImage alloc] init]];
   Tabbar.tabBar.layer.borderWidth = 0.0f;
   Tabbar.tabBar.layer.borderColor =[UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
   Tabbar.tabBar.layer.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
   Tabbar.tabBar.tintColor=CLEAR_COLOR;
   Tabbar.tabBar.barTintColor=CLEAR_COLOR;
```

***2)Try :***

```
    CALayer * superLayer = [UITabBar appearance].layer;
    CALayer * layer = [CALayer layer];
    layer.bounds = CGRectMake (0.0f, 0.0f, 62.0f, 56.0f);
    layer.contents = (id) [UIImage imageNamed: @"tras_tabbg-min"].CGImage;
    layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake (0.5f, 1.0f);
    layer.position = CGPointMake (superLayer.bounds.size.width / 2.0f, superLayer.bounds.size.height);
    layer.zPosition = 1.0f;
    [[UITabBar appearance].layer addSublayer: layer];
```

***3) Try : (crash the app)***

```
[self.tabBar setValue:@(YES) forKeyPath:@"_hidesShadow"];
```

***4) Try: ***

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImageName"]];
[UITabBar appearance].layer.borderWidth = 0.0f;
[UITabBar appearance].clipsToBounds = true;
```

**Output :**

[image]

I want Border Hear also. this is a background Image.

> Note : I want background Image on tabbar it is not nil or clear

If Any solution kindly reply.

Answer (score 5):

if >= iOS 10

```
tabBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.black
```

else < iOS 10:

```
tabBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
tabBar.backgroundImage = UIImage()
```

Answer (score 0):

> In the view did load method of custom tab bar use this code.(swift 3)
>   Convert this to objective c

```
 class CustomTabBarController: UITabBarController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tabBar.backgroundImage = UIImage()
        self.tabBar.shadowImage = UIImage()

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This line is comming from your custom image or color

```
self.tabBar.backgroundImage = nil
self.tabBar.shadowImage = nil
```

and
Check view behid tabBar

Comment: Hello @Qamar its works but my Background Image are remove i want background image.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work. Is working for iOS 9. Try it.

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage alloc] init]]; 
[[UITabBar appearance] setShadowImage:[[UIImage alloc] init]];
```

If the above solution doesn't worked. Try this. This code is tested in iOS 10 and 10.1, its working fine.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    [[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImageName"]];
    [UITabBar appearance].layer.borderWidth = 0.0f;
    [UITabBar appearance].clipsToBounds = true;
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: @shivay its work but by border are remove from tabbar

Comment: Share Screenshot @sohil

Comment: i have edit my question please check it *Try 4* @shivaay

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom UITabBar Class & override layoutSubviews method as below:

```
-(void)layoutSubviews{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    for (UIView *view in self.subviews){
        if([NSStringFromClass([view class]) isEqualToString:@"_UIBarBackground"]){
            if(view.subviews.count>1){
                [view.subviews[1] removeFromSuperview];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

**iOS 10:**

```
UITabBar.appearance().layer.borderWidth = 0.0
UITabBar.appearance().clipsToBounds = true
```